# How to use if else condition in a button - flutter

Tags: button, flutter, conditional-statements

I am trying to show an alert dialog after user has pressed this button after a certain condition is met. if the text is empty it will pop a dialog however using what i tried below, it still pops up the dialog even when text is not empty after pressing button.

```
RaisedButton(
                onPressed: priceController.text == ""
                    ? () => showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text("Enter a price"),
                          );
                        })
                    : () => apiRequest(url, {
                          'price': priceController.text,
                          'user_id': "user2"
                        }),
                child: Text("Set Level"),
              );
```

Comment: Indeed it's weird it should work, what about using `String.isEmpty` method, or refractor you code with an `if/else` bloc

Comment: can you show your full code, maybe you are doing something wrong with the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of having two functions just have one and write your logic inside.
like this:

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (priceController.text == "") {
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Enter a price"),
            );
          });
    } else {
      apiRequest(url, {'price': priceController.text, 'user_id': "user2"});
    }
  },
  child: Text("Set Level"),
);
```